# How to get a jpg image out of a json file

Tags: json, instagram

I have downloaded my account data off of instagram. A large chunk of the downloaded files where JSON so I got a json opener on my android phone and opened them. I could read all the messages fine but the images show the caption the date taken and the path. Is there anyway to open these images as images and not just as words or letters.

Answer (score 0):

If the images in jpeg format. You can copy base64 image value from json and using [this](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) to show image. You can also do it by html see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html#answer-8499716) stack topic.